# Worklight 6.1 : jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to add autocomplete feature to an input without changing the pre-bundled jQuery in IBM Worklight. So, I tried to add only jQuery UI, but **"$(...).autocomplete is not a function"** error message is always displayed.

Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including jquery-ui javascript file and calling that function in javascript.